# ExtJS 4 MVC Structure & Testing

Tags: unit-testing, extjs, model-view-controller

I'm developing an application with extJS following the MVC pattern but I'm unsure where to put the business logic to keep it testable.

Lets look at the following example:
I have a store containing some numbers. If I click on a Button (Button1) I want to do some calculation and want to show the result in a popup afterwards.

Here is my Approach:
Button --onClick--> Controller1(event listener) --> Controller2 (collect the numbers out of the store, do the calculation) ---> Controller1(async call with result) creates a new popup

When doing it like this, I can easily test the calculation in Controller2, as it is absolutely decoupled from any view.

This leads to two sort of controllers:
- Controllers that interact with views (event-listener and popup-initiator)
- Controllers with business logic

Is this the right approach ?

Comment: what you really want now? why you need two controller to do such a simple operation?

Comment: @vino20 The simplicity of the operation shouldn't matter. The OP is more a question of architecture in general, rather than how to accomplish a specific task.

Comment: @existdissolve, I accept your words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a bit of a debate about this. The vanilla MVC approach built into Ext JS is typically leverages controllers for both business logic and view event management. So if you were to follow any of the many Ext JS MVC tutorials out there, you'll probably find that pattern.

Others, however, prefer to decouple the view even more, opting for a ViewController of sorts, such as what you've suggested. You might check out DeftJS for a nice implementation of this. http://deftjs.org/

Ultimately, I argue it doesn't matter. I'm of the opinion that you should write an app in a way that:

1. Follows some set of standard conventions
2. Makes sense to you
3. Works
4. Is sustainable and scalable

I think both of these approaches easily facilitate these requirements (I've done both), so ultimately I would argue it comes down to your preference and what you're most comfortable implementing.